# Preserves naively $\mathbb{A}^{1}$-homotopic maps

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, model-categories, motivic-homotopy, simplicial-presheaves

I've been studying $\mathbb{A}^{1}$-homotopy recently and would like some guidance with the question below. Thank you so much.

**Setup**

Fix $k$ a field of characteristic zero. Let $Sm_{k}$ denote the category of smooth $k$-varieies. Let $\tau$ be a Grothendieck topology on the category of simplicial presheaves of smooth $k$-varieties. Consider this site with the $\tau$-local injective model structure and then Bausfield localize at the family $\{\mathbb{A}^{1}\times U\rightarrow U\}$ for all $U \in Sm_{k}$.

Given a presheaf of groups $\mathrm{G}$, we can define a simplicial presheaf $B\mathrm{G}:Sm_{k}^{op}\rightarrow sSet$ as follows: $B\mathrm{G}(U)=B(\mathrm{G}(U)) \in sSet$ for all $U \in Sm_{k}$.

**Question**

Let $\mathrm{G}$ and $\mathrm{H}$ be presheaves of groups. Let  $f_{1},f_{2}:\mathrm{G}\rightarrow \mathrm{H}$ be considered as morphisms of simplicial presheaves.

I would like to know if the following is true. If $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ are naively $\mathbb{A}^{1}$-homotopic, then so are $Bf_{1}$ and $Bf_{2}$.

Comment: Although not explicitly stated in the help centre (which seems to be a generic page for all SE websites), it is considered good practice to add at least one [top level tag](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/1458/82179).

Comment: Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: An $\mathbb{A}^1$-homotopy between $f_0$ and $f_1$ is a morphism $h:G\to H^{\mathbb{A}^1}$. Since the assignment $G\mapsto BG$ is a functor and since we obviously have $B(H^{\mathbb{A}^1})=(BH)^{\mathbb{A}^1}$, the answer is yes (assuming that $h$ is morphism of groups, of course).

Comment: So, there is a natural isomorphism between $B\mathbb{A}^{1}$ and $\mathbb{A}^{1}$?

Comment: Not as (pre)sheaves. If $X$ is a sheaf of sets and $F$ a (pre)sheaf, then $F^X$ is the (pre)sheaf $U\mapsto F(X\times U)$. For $F$ a sheaf of groups, $F^X$ is a sheaf of groups and one checks rather directly that $B(F^X)=B(F)^X$. There is no structure on $X$. Take $X=\mathbb{A}^1$.